# How can I lookup the registering info of an ISSN number?

Tags: publications, publishers

While applying for an ISSN, applicants are asked to provide publisher name, country/city, contact info and editor name. How/where can I look up an ISSN number to get these info?

Of course for a single ISSN number, I can google, find the journal site and contact them via the website. But I am doing a research on a big number of ISSNs.

Moreover, how can I be sure it is not a fake number?!! Anyone can comeup with an 8 digit number, and call it an ISSN! IS there a main ISSN portal/service, where I can lookup ISSN numbers?

thanks

Comment: See http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/the-issn-international-register/ for access options. It requires subscription; it is not freely available online. You could also have found this information from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number#Availability :)

Comment: If your research gives you DoIs for the publications, you can often scrape the ISSNs of the journals from those (typically, they are the 8 digits that follow the last '/'), and the information via dx.doi.org will normally give you information about the publisher.

Comment: Worldcat is a decent option

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer:

You can check if the ISSN is 'fake' or not at [this ISSN-Validator website](http://journal-index.org/ISSN-validator/). It doesn't provide much useful info though. All numbers entered are either 'invalid' or 'valid' with no further information given.

Comment: This probably just verifies the check digit as explained at http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number. Anyone who can do arithmetic can produce a fake number with a valid check digit.